# Why do multiple items get added to my cart in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopping-cart

thank you for your time.
I was having a problem adding the products on my list to my cart.

When I refresh the page the first "Add to cart" button I click adds multiple items (eg. 200) instead of one but after that, it works accordingly. It's always added to that pre-existing number too, even when I refresh the page.
Here´s one of the products HTML:

```
  <!-- 3  -->
  <li class="item-a"> 
    <div class="box">
   <p class=cafetera1>GRAN LATTISIMA</p>
       <!-- model  -->
       <img src="./img/Maquina-nespresso-3.jpg" class="model-3">
       <!-- details  -->
       <div class="details">
           <p>$23.098,56</p>  
           <div class="botones">
           <button class="btn-minus">-</button>
           <button id="boton3" class="add-cart ">Agregar al carrito</button>
           <button class="btn-plus">+</button></div>
           <input type="hidden" value="23098.56">
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
let carts = document.querySelectorAll(".add-cart");

let products = [
    {
        "name":"ESSENZA MINI D PLUS",
        "tag": "primera",
        "price": 24765.08,
        "inCart": 0
    },
    {
        "name":"PIXIE-NESPRESSO",
        "tag": "segunda",
        "price": 19004.32,
        "inCart": 0
    },
    {
        "name":"GRAN LATTISIMA",
        "tag": "tercera",
        "price": 23098.56,
        "inCart": 0
    },
    {
        "name":"ESSENZA MINI C",
        "tag": "cuarta",
        "price": 30983.09,
        "inCart": 0
    }
]


for (let i=0; i < carts.length; i++) {
    carts[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        cartNumbers(products[i]);
        totalCost(products[i]);
    });
}

function onLoadCartNumbers(){
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers");
    if(productNumbers){
        document.querySelector(".carrito a span").textContent = productNumbers;
    }
}

function cartNumbers(product){
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers");

    productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);

    if(productNumbers){
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers + 1);
        document.querySelector(".carrito a span").textContent = productNumbers + 1;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", 1);
        document.querySelector(".carrito a span").textContent = 1;
    }

    setItems(product);
}

function setItems(product) {
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    if(cartItems != null){
        if(cartItems[product.tag] != undefined) {
            cartItems = {...cartItems, [product.tag]:product }
        }
    } else {
        product.inCart = 1;
        cartItems = { [product.tag]: product }
    }

    localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}
```

Comment: You want to start over (with zero product in the cart) on each page refresh?

Comment: I want to be able to add one product the first time i click the button, it is automatically adding what seems like a random number the first time, then it adds them by one.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have tried clearing localStorage.
In setItems try using --
function setItems(product){

```
let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

if(cartItems != null){
    if(**cartItems[product.id] == undefined**){
        cartItems = {
            ...cartItems, 
            [product.tag]: product
        }
    }
    **cartItems[product.tag].inCart += 1;**
}
else{
    product.inCart = 1;
    cartItems = {
        [product.tag] : product
    }
}

localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
```

}